# Dictionary or list?

Tags: python

I need to be able to store data, one being a number and one being the number of times it appeared. I have a for loop that calls a method that returns a dictionary:

```
for x in range(total_holidays):
    t = trial()
    y = y + "\n" + str(x+1) + "," + str(t["brown"]) + "," + str(t["rainbow"]) + "," + str(t["nothing"]) + "," + str(t["days"])
    total += t["days"]
    #print total
    if x%10000 == 0:
        y0.append(y)
        y = ""
```

Basically I need to count how many times t['days'] happens, the number changes almost every time. If you want the full code look here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193846/how-many-trials-would-you-expect-to-give-you-an-accurate-answer

So how would I do this and then I need to print it all out after.

`y` is text for a csv file, and total is used to calculate the average.

---

As suggested by mgilson should I use this?

```
from collections import Counter

a = []
for x in range(total_holidays):
    t = trial()
    y = y + "\n" + str(x+1) + "," + str(t["brown"]) + "," + str(t["rainbow"]) + "," + str(t["nothing"]) + "," + str(t["days"])
    total += t["days"]
    a.append(t['days'])
    #print total
    if x%10000 == 0:
        y0.append(y)
        y = ""
z = Counter(a)
print z
```

Should I have something like that?

Comment: Your code has several bits I don't understand: for example, you check whether `dr == 1`, but as near as I can tell `dr` can never be 1. It looks to me like there are two `db += 1` lines which are questionable.  Without knowing what the problem is, though, it's hard to know whether your code actually gives the right answer.

Comment: Crap. Didn't notice that. Must have just read the other line and didn't think. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for that btw. Changes the average from 12.4 to 9.3

Comment: I would be a little worried that your code has other bugs lurking.  Your `trial()` function is hard to read and has a lot of duplication -- most of your lines are written three times -- which is a sign that you need to abstract a level higher.

Comment: I need to fix a few things, I know, it was written in like 10 - 20 minutes, it was more of a testing thing to base other things on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the `collections.Counter` type, a `dict` subtype specialized for this kind of task:

```
import collections
days_occurred = collections.Counter()

for ...:
    t = trial()
    days_occurred[t['days']] += 1

# total is now sum(days_occurred.itervalues())

# you print the counts by iterating over the dict

for days, count in days_occurred.iteritems():
    print "%d: %d" % (days, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to construct a CSV file manually. Python already has a built-in module for this:

```
import csv

writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'wb'))

# ...

for x in range(total_holidays):
  t = trial()

  writer.writerow([x + 1, t['brown'], t['rainbow'], t['nothing'], t['days']])
  total += t['days']
```

Aside from that, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hmm, I shall use that, and I want to count how many times a number appears, like lets say trail()['days'] returned `1,1,2,2,2,5,6,9,1` I want something that tells me `1=3, 2=3,5=1,6=1,9=1`

Comment: @SmartLemon -- If that's the case, you can get it using a `collections.Counter`  (which would return a dictionary)